# Understanding Diophantine Equation Proof /w link

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

There is a proof that I'm trying to understand, but the textbook I have isn't making any sense and my teachers explanations are not very clear to non-existent. I'm trying to understand why: 
$$x^4 - y^4 = z^2$$ has no solutions. I've found a proof of this theorem [here](http://planetmath.org/x4y4z2hasnosolutionsinpositiveintegers), but there is little to no explanation as to why each step was taken. I was hoping someone out there who understands this proof well can explain it to me, or provide an alternative way to prove it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually first prove that if $x^2+y^2=z^2$ for some integers, then the right-angled triangle with sides $x,y,z$ cannot have square area. You can find a proof of that here: [Pythagorean triples and perfect squares](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365445/pythagorean-triples-and-perfect-squares/365599#365599). Then if there is an integer solution to your equation, you can deduce a right-angled triangle with integer sides and square area.

You can also find a direct proof here: [Solving $x^4-y^4=z^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/153546/solving-x4-y4-z2/153549#153549)